# How to check an input type=checkbox with React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

Having a Checkbox List component with two checkboxes. Initially the first one is checked and the second one is unchecked.

I want to write a test that must verify when clicking on the second checkbox to be checked too.

The styled component translates to this html:

**first checkbox**

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  aria-label="checkbox"
  name="checkbox-array"
  value="first"
  checked="" // here is the difference
  id="first"
/>
```

**second checkbox**

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  aria-label="checkbox"
  name="checkbox-array"
  value="second"
  id="second"
/>
```

The unit test:

```
  it('should select second option when clicked', () => {
    const secondOption = screen.getByLabelText('second');
    expect(secondOption).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(secondOption).not.toBeChecked();
    fireEvent.click(secondOption); 

    expect(secondOption).toBeChecked(); // it fails here
  });
```

The test fails, it doesn't pass the last `expect` and has the error message:

> only inputs with type="checkbox" or type="radio" or elements with
> role="checkbox", role="menuitemcheckbox", role="menuitemradio",
> role="option", role="radio", role="switch" or role="treeitem" and a
> valid aria-checked attribute can be used with .toBeChecked(). Use
> .toHaveValue() instead

Also tried with `toHaveValue` but it seems to not recognise this method. How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble with the checked state of my checkbox not being registered properly. After doing some digging, I realized that the issue was with my selection method. I was able to successfully solve my issue by using getByRole.

```
  it("check that checkbox gets checked", () => {
    render(
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        aria-label="checkbox"
        name="checkbox-array"
        value="second"
        id="second"
      />
    );

    const checkbox = screen.getByRole("checkbox", { name: "checkbox" });
    expect(checkbox).not.toBeChecked();
    fireEvent.click(checkbox);
    expect(checkbox).toBeChecked();
  });
```